# unable to display Chinese character by xelatex under OS X EI Caption and sublime 2

Tags: macos, latex, sublimetext, xelatex

When I just recently update my OS X system, the pdf compiled by xelatex can no longer display Chinese (The characters are missing). I look at the log and it says

```
    This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99991 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded                      format=xelatex 2015.3.9)  17 OCT 2015 21:18
    entering extended mode
    (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd
    File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B)
    Missing character: There is no 林 in font ptmr7t!
    Missing character: There is no 星 in font ptmr7t!
    Missing character: There is no 宇 in font ptmr7t!
```

By the way, I am using the sublime latex tool plugin.

Comment: This is mostly because you have incorrect settings in your tex source files. What is [a minimal, correct, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I met this problem too.
Though my language is Japanese, I think it has a same solution.

Try this:

- Open Sublimetext > Preferences > Browse Packages
- then open file LaTexTools > builders > traditionalBuilder.py
- Comment out line 18-20, DEFAULT_COMMAND_LATEXMK
- And paste this:

  ```
  DEFAULT_COMMAND_LATEXMK = ["latexmk", "-cd",
              "-e", "$latex = 'platex -synctex=1 -src-specials -interaction=nonstopmode'",
              "-e", "$biber = 'biber %O --bblencoding=utf8 -u -U --output_safechars %B'",
              "-e", "$bibtex = 'pbibtex %O %B'",
              "-e", "$makeindex = 'makeindex %O -o %D %S'",
              "-e", "$dvipdf = 'dvipdfmx %O -o %D %S'",
              "-e", "$pdf_mode = '3'",
              "-e", "$pdf_update_method = '0'",
              "-e", "$pdf_previewer = 'open -a preview.app'",
              "-f", "-norc", "-gg", "-pdfdvi"]
  ```
- Press Cmd+Shift+P and input "recon", then Run `LatexTools:Reconfigure and migrate Settings`
- Quit Sublime text(not close window, but quit)
- Reopen and edit tex file(or remove old log files), then build